# How to create left join using only an inner join?

Tags: sql, left-join, inner-join

I recently had an interview and I was asked how to create a left join by only using an inner join. The interviewer said to me some of the software they use in the company doesn't allow the use of left joins so we have to use inner joins to do them. I was stubbed with the question and I was wondering does anyone here know how to do it?

Comment: using *only* an `INNER JOIN`?, does that means no `EXISTS`, `UNION`, etc?

Comment: @Lamak yeah he made it out to me that I could only use an inner join. I only know the basics of SQL so maybe using union and exists is the only way to do it.

Comment: I am intrigued, could this be a trick question? The moment we use `INNER` the non matching rows are kicked out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my crack at it. It is basically turning the inner join into a cross apply, then NULLing out values if they do not match the actual desired join condition.

```
CREATE TABLE #testusers (userid INT)

CREATE TABLE #testusers2 (userID INT)

INSERT INTO #testusers (userid)
VALUES (1)
    , (2)
    , (3)

INSERT INTO #testusers2 (userid)
VALUES (2), (5), (1)


--Expecting to see one result due to straight inner join
SELECT t1.*
    , t2.*
FROM #testusers t1
INNER JOIN #testusers2 t2
    ON t1.userid = t2.userid

--Forcing all results by basically doing a cross apply and then NULLing out non matching values based on the join condition
SELECT distinct t1.*
    , MAX(CASE 
        WHEN t1.userid <> t2.userID
            THEN NULL
        ELSE t2.userid
        END) AS userid
FROM #testusers t1
INNER JOIN #testusers2 t2
    ON t1.userid = t2.userid
        OR 1 = 1
GROUP BY t1.userid
```

Works for VARCHAR too.

```
CREATE TABLE #testusersnames (username varchar(10))

CREATE TABLE #testusersnames2 (username varchar(10))

INSERT INTO #testusersnames (username)
VALUES ('Tom')
    , ('Jane')
    , ('Dick')

INSERT INTO #testusersnames2 (username)
VALUES ('Tom'), ('Sally'), ('Mary')

SELECT t1.*
    , t2.*
FROM #testusersnames t1
INNER JOIN #testusersnames2 t2
    ON t1.username = t2.username

--Forcing all results by basically doing a cross apply and then NULLing out non matching values based on the join condition
SELECT distinct t1.*
    , MAX(CASE 
        WHEN t1.username <> t2.username
            THEN NULL
        ELSE t2.username
        END) AS username
FROM #testusersnames t1
INNER JOIN #testusersnames2 t2
    ON t1.username = t2.username
        OR 1 = 1
GROUP BY t1.username
```

Comment: This only works because the table 2 has only 1 row, if you add one more, this won't work as a `LEFT JOIN` anymore

Comment: Updated to accommodate more rows.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my attempt. Verified on http://sqliteonline.com/

Limitations: I will have to "null" out the columns I don't want to be returned.

**Edit** OP says no UNION, thus this answer does not apply.

```
CREATE TABLE demo (id int, name varchar(32));

CREATE TABLE demo_details (demo_id int, description varchar(64));

INSERT INTO demo_details
VALUES (1,
        'Woohooooooooo');

SELECT *
FROM demo d
INNER JOIN demo_details dd ON d.id = dd.demo_id
UNION
SELECT d.*,
       NULL,
       NULL
FROM demo d
INNER JOIN demo_details dd ON d.id <> dd.demo_id;
```

Comment: op said no `UNION`

Comment: Are you sure? Antonio said: "so maybe using union and exists is the only way to do it". That does not sound like he excludes these options totally to me.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT * FROM Table2
  UNION 
  SELECT {NULL for every column in Table2}
) t2
  ON 1=1
WHERE t1.id = t2.id
OR t2.id IS NULL
```

Comment: One restriction is no `UNION`

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
-- dummy data
with a as (
    select 
        1 as id, 
        'A' as name
    union
    select 2, 'B'
),

b as  (
    select 
        1 as id, 
        'C' as value 
)

select *, 
    (select b.value
        from 
    b 
        inner join a a1 
            on a1.id=b.id 
            and a1.id = a.id
    ) as bvalue 
from
    a
```

You'd have to write a subquery for every value you wanted to left join, sounds fun!

And if your subquery returned multiple values, you could write a hairy windowing partition to ensure each row was joined only one time.

Answer (score 0):

I see the solution is not to try and do something fancy in a select statement, but to manually recreate the left join. So you create a temp table, give it an id value from the bigger table, populate it from the smaller table, and then inner join on that. It's not very performance-friendly, but I imagine that you could transition the temp table into a permanent table that always kept a value for all the first table's ids while only storing values from the second table.

```
--setup (optional for first time)
DROP TABLE demo;
DROP TABLE demoLeftJoin;
DROP TABLE temp;
--setup
CREATE TABLE demo(id int, lastName varchar(32), hint varchar(120));
CREATE TABLE demoLeftJoin(id int, name varchar(32), hint varchar(120));
--populate demo
INSERT INTO demo VALUES (1, 'Doe', 'nothing');
INSERT INTO demo VALUES (2, 'Doe', 'nothing2');
INSERT INTO demo VALUES (3, 'Deer', 'nothing3');
--populate demoLeftJoin
INSERT INTO demoLeftJoin VALUES (1, 'John', 'nothing');
INSERT INTO demoLeftJoin VALUES (2, 'Jane', 'nothing2');
INSERT INTO demoLeftJoin VALUES (3, 'John', 'nothing3');
INSERT INTO demoLeftJoin VALUES (4, 'Buck', 'nothing4');
INSERT INTO demoLeftJoin VALUES (5, 'Truck', 'nothing5');
--create temp table
CREATE TABLE temp(id int, lastName varchar(32), hint varchar(120));
--make sure it will match an inner join for all values from demoLeftJoin
INSERT INTO temp select id, NULL, NULL from demoLeftJoin;
--populate temp with values you want from demo
UPDATE temp
SET 
    lastName = (SELECT d.lastName FROM demo d WHERE temp.id = d.id), 
    hint = (SELECT d.hint FROM demo d WHERE temp.id = d.id)
WHERE temp.id in (SELECT d.id FROM demo d);
-- perform inner join
SELECT * FROM demoLeftJoin dlj INNER JOIN temp t on dlj.id = t.id;
```

Your results should give you the equivalent of an inner join. You may notice that the hint column is now null for your 4th and 5th results. I've left that in order to show you a potential problem with overlapping names. The easiest solution is to make sure that column names don't conflict e.g., name the 'hint' column to 'hint2' on the temp table.

Answer (score 0):

+1 to @dfundako's answer, that's the way I'd do it if the requirement is to do it in a single SQL query.

Another option is to define a VIEW that does the outer join

```
CREATE VIEW joinedTable AS
  SELECT ... FROM table1 LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 ON ...;
```

Then the client can do a simple query without violating its rules:

```
SELECT ... FROM joinedTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

Do the select from Table A to Table B "Inner Join"
Do the select from Table B where not in Table A

Then combine them with a variety of methods.  In Sql you can do a Union, or you could select them into a table or temp table and then select the temp table.

Or you could combine them on the client tool that is making the sql command.

It may be a trick question.  The person asking the question may not know what he or she is doing.  I have been given interview questions where I answered right.  But the person asking did not know the answer correctly and was seeking a candidate with the same wrong understand as they have.  It could also be a question to see how you react.  Do you explode, do you make accusations, or do you react reasonably?

Things to think about.

Comment: I have been asked how to do a many to many relationship in sql with just two tables.  Not sure if it was a trick question or an incompetent one.

Comment: Yeah he was just doing it to see how I would react to a question he knew I wouldn't know the answer too. The interviewer definitely knew what he was talking about and I was told this was his style of interviewing before I went in.